# How can I exclude private constructors which is written in TypeScript from function coverage using nyc?

Tags: typescript, istanbul, nyc

I want to exclude `private constructor` from **function coverage**.
Actually I prefer to use `private constructor` in `Factory Pattern`.

#### Sample Code

```js
class Instance { }
class InstanceA extends Instance { 
  public constructor() { super(); }
}
class InstanceB extends Instance { 
  public constructor() { super(); }
}
class InstanceC extends Instance { 
  public constructor() { super(); }
}

class Factory {
  private constructor() {
    /* I want to exclude this constructor */
  }

  public static createInstance(option: number): Instance {
    switch(option) {
      case 1:
        return new InstanceA();
      case 2:
        return new InstanceB();
      case 3:
        return new InstanceC();
      default:
        return undefined;
    }
  }
}


class ClientCode {
  private name: string;
  private age: number;
  private myInstance: Instance;

  public constructor(name: string, age: number, option: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.myInstance = Factory.createInstance(option);
  }

  public foo(): void {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

#### `nyc` options

```
  "nyc": {
    "cache": false,
    "extension": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "include": [
      "script/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "script/entries/",
      "**/GlobalEnums.ts"
    ],
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register/transpile-only",
      "source-map-support/register"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "html",
      "text",
      "text-summary"
    ],
    "temp-dir": "./coverage/.nyc_output"
  }
```

As I mentioned in `comment`, I want to exclude `private constructor`. 
This makes my coverage percentage lower.
How can I exclude this?

Comment: Alternatively: don't use a class if you don't plan on instantiating this. It's not Java, you have other options!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `nyc` is just a CLI wrapper around istanbul you should be able to use its [special comments](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md) to disable it:

```js
class Factory {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  private constructor() {
    /* I want to exclude this constructor */
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to let other developers read non-necessary comments. Can you please suggest any other options? But, If I have no choice, I will consider to use `comments` which is you answered for me.

Comment: The only clean suggestion I would have in this case is to implement a custom babel plugin that would work together with `babel-typescript` parser. This plugin would look for private constructors and insert the comment node for later consumption by nyc. This is pretty complicated though. You could also just run a regex on your code to inject the comment but that is error prone and would modify your files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds like I need more resources to test and to measure coverage. Since I'm using a `Webpack`, so let me search other plugins more for it.